# Swift 4 UITableViewCell first tap doesn't call segue, and second tap calls segue with the first cell data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a problem with a TableView with cells using a XIB file, when I first tap on a cell, it does nothing, and when I tap on another cell, the segue is called, but with the data of the first cell tapped. I'm using "self.performSegue" on the "didDeselectRowAt" tableView Function. Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     _ = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell") as! CardTableViewCell?
     self.eachCard = cardsArray[indexPath.row]

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCard", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let card = segue.destination as? SingleShotViewController
    if segue.identifier == "showCard" {
        card?.name = eachCard["name"] as! String
        card?.type = eachCard["type"] as! String
        if eachCard["imageUrl"] == nil {
            card?.imgURL = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=264373&type=card"
        } else {
        card?.imgURL = eachCard["imageUrl"] as! String
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this overload instead of didDeselectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        _ = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell") as! CardTableViewCell?
     self.eachCard = cardsArray[indexPath.row]

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCard", sender: tableView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a cell in a tableview, first the didSelectRow function is called. When you tap it one more time, the didDeselectRow function is called.
Just change the function to didSelectRow and it will work fine.

Comment: but the function is the didSelectRow, I don't use the didDeselectRow on this code.

Comment: @Douugr Can you verify if you used `didSelectRowAt` or `didDeselectRowAt`?

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully you will find yourself using "didDeselectRowAt indexPath" which why in the second touch you preform the segue and delegate is being called so instead of that just change "didDeselectRowAt indexPath" to "didSelectRow  indexPath" and it will work fine